# Clean up HTML keeping custom tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, nltk, tidy

I have an string like following.

```
<GPE>LUSAKA</GPE> (<ORG>AP</ORG>) -- X&Y Ltd. &amp; M.K. Ltd will be merged.
```

How can I make it valid XML so my etree.XMLParser does not throw error. I need to convert it to something like.

```
<GPE>LUSAKA</GPE> (<ORG>AP</ORG>) -- X&amp;Y Ltd. &amp; M.K. Ltd will be merged.
```

For this I tried to use `tidylib`. But it removed all the custom tags. See the code

```
options = {
    'wrap': 0,
    'indent': 0,
    'output-xhtml': 1,
    'numeric-entities': 1
}
html, warnings = tidylib.tidy_fragment(data, options)
```

Output is

```
LUSAKA (AP) -- X&amp;Y Ltd. &amp; M.K. Ltd will be merged.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('<GPE>LUSAKA</GPE> (<ORG>AP</ORG>) -- X&Y Ltd. &amp; M.K. Ltd will be merged.', etree.HTMLParser())
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<html><body><gpe>LUSAKA</gpe> (<org>AP</org>) -- X&amp;Y Ltd. &amp; M.K. Ltd will be merged.</body></html>'
>>> tree.xpath('//gpe/text()')
['LUSAKA']
```

Comment: Wow! Thats impressive. Feeling noob asking such a question. BTW any way to remove `<HTML><BODY>` tags? I mean is there any options for that?

Comment: I can parse. I need to make sure it only adds <body> and <html> tags but nothing else.

Comment: I think its safe to assume that, should be checked though

Comment: btw, I think beautifulsoup can do this as well, personally I prefer lxml over all the rest...